# Providing admin actions to group members in a multi tenant django CRM application

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am about to start designing a multitenant CRM solution.

The interesting libraries that appear are 
the list of libraries that can be used are - https://dpaste.de/vvzWw/ (you can suggest edits if you wish as to which libraries would be better for a multi tenant django crm soln)

Now my major question is every instance(tenant) of the crm will have admin. 
The django admin provides an awesome admin interface, I want the admin to be able to perform only contact/user management feature from the admin interface, and nothing else, that too only the users that belong to his sub-domain.

Can this be achieved or will I have to design a separate interface for the tenant admin?

Answer (score 3):

YMMV but my own experience is that django-admin is a PITA to customize beyond simple things, and that I get better results writing a custom interface when the users needs are anything more than simple low-level CRUD (and don't get me wrong, django-admin is really great).

Now restricting which ModelAdmins are available to a given user and restricting the ModelAdmins querysets according to the current user is definitly not a problem in django-admin so if that's all you need you can always start that way and only start writing your own admin interface when you find the domain requires something more complex / specialized than what django-admin provides.

Comment: thnaks for the answer, so what I have understood is, if there is low level CRUD I should be able to do stuff with ModelAdmin restrictions. Another thing if you take a look at the libraries would you suggest any other changes https://dpaste.de/vvzWw/ Thanks for your answer.